# Pass id to a React Component without params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I know there's a way to pass an id to another component via params with the **useParams()** hook.
The thing is I don't want to show my user's ids on the URL.
So my way of doing it is via **Link**.
I put a **Button** and wrap it with a **Link** component.
There I pass a pathname and in the state I pass the user data.
Like this:

```
      <tbody>
        {persons.map((person, idx) => {
          return (
            <tr key={idx}>
              <td>{person.id}</td>
              <td>{person.name}</td>
              <td>{person.last_name}</td>
              <td>{person.age}</td>
              <td>{person.phone}</td>
              <td>{person.occupation}</td>
              <td>
                <Link to={{ pathname: "/path", state: person }}>
                  <Button> Edit </Button>
                </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
```

So my question is:
Is it right to do it this way? If not. Is there another way?

Comment: IMO, we have different ways to pass param from one to another component. We choose any way to do this based on the requirement. So, I think the code above is right. [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Comment: Code is correct it will work, but if you want that a user will be able se send the URL and the person using that url should land on the same view so that will not happen.